# How to read and update language MST file (1033.mst) which is part of MSI Package using C# windows application?

Tags: c#, installshield, windows-application-packaging

I have created MSI Package using InstallShield@2014 supporting languages
English - United States(1033)
Chinese - Taiwan(1028)
Chinese - China(2052)

Language MST file (1033.mst, 1028.mst & 2052.mst) is embaded with MSI Package.
My requerment is to update MIS Package License Agreement(EULA) for all supporting languages from any tool & Repackage MSI Package and share to end user.
When end user install MSI Package he/she can see updated License Agreement(EULA) for all supporting languages.

I tried many way to update MIS Package License Agreement(EULA) but unable to find correct way to update License Agreement(EULA).

Please help me to update License Agreement(EULA) in MSI Package using C# windows application.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.